# Absolute values and Galois action

Tags: galois-theory, group-actions, local-field

Let L be a finite Galois extension of the local field K.Then why is the following true?
$$|\sigma(x)|=|x|,\forall \sigma\in\text{Gal}(L/K),x\in L$$

Comment: Because if $L/K$ is a finite extension and $K$ is locally compact with respect to some absolute value, then this absolute value has at most one extension to $L$. If $|\cdot |$ is an absolute value on $L$, then $|x|$ and $|\sigma(x)|$ (for a fixed $\sigma$) are extensions of the same absolute value on $K$, and so they must be equal.

Comment: Alternatively can I think of it like this:Since it is a local field,$\sigma$ maps the maximal ideal to itself.So the absolute value of any element remains invariant under Galois action

Comment: Which maximal ideal do you mean? In what ring?

Comment: Maximal ideal of the ring of integers of the local field I mean.